# screen goes black when keyboard hides

Tags: android, keyboard

After typing in the input text the keyboard get hides but the screen goes black color.

i have tried like this

```
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/noAnimTheme"
             android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan|stateHidden"
```

I have used the above code in Manifest file.

Could anybody give any clear idea to clear the black screen.@Thanks

Comment: it goes black and stays black? What device are you testing on?

Comment: @FoamyGuy samsung galaxy

Comment: @FoamyGuy can you tell why its happen like this]

Comment: "samsung galaxy" is not a device, that is a whole line of devices. can you be any more specific about which one you have? And no, I don't know why it is doing that, I can tell you though that is outside the normal system behavior.

Comment: @FoamyGuy Samsung galaxy I9000

Comment: any idea why.. i get black screen when screen hides in xamarin forms application